# Debian - default ip per user?

Tags: sockets, networking, ip, debian, bind

I got a server that has 64 public IPv4 adresses. Is there any way to set default IP per user on Debian? I don't mean virtual server setup. Or if not, is there any console application to bind other application (that doesn't support IP binding nativly) to selected IP?
Best regards,
FlashT

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

you could use a crafty firewall that marks packages originating from processes owned by a given user and then rewrites packages accordingly, as described [here](http://blog.sebastien.raveau.name/2009/04/per-process-routing.html).